# Typescript Observables and Promises

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am attempting to implement OIDC in an Angular project. Eveything was going great until I tried to implement an HPPT interceptor to set the Authorization header.
I have a method on the auth service that returns the token as a promise:
`

```
getAccessToken()
  {
    return this._userManager.getUser().then(user =>
      {
        if(!!user && !user.expired)
        {
          return user.access_token
        }
        else
        {
          return null
        }
      })
  }
```

`Here is my intercept method`

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
  {
    if(req.url.startsWith(Constants.avlApiRootUrl))
    {
      return from(this._authService.getAccessToken().then(token =>{
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${ token }`)
        const authReq = req.clone({headers})
        return next.handle(authReq)
      }))
   }
    else
    {
      return next.handle(req)
    }
  }
```

`
When I try to call this from the intercept class on the HTTPInterceptor I get an error:
Type 'Promise<Observable>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': source, operator, lift, subscribe, and 3 more.ts(2740)

I understand that I am returning the wrong type but everything I can find about this says to use a toPromise method that has been depreciated. Can anyone tell me how to do this, I'm out of ideas. More than having someone write my code for me (which I would take at this point) I'd really like to understand this so if you can point to a write up or documentation That would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're returning `next.hande()` within your promise, it's returning `Observable<Promise<Observable<T>>>`.
You need to return plain `Observable<T>`:

To accomplish this you can make modifications to your observable stream using `.pipe()` with some operators. We can start with your promise wrapped in `from()`, like you had, then `map` the result into a new headers object, then into an auth reqeust object, then finally into a call to `next.handle()`:

```js
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(req.url.startsWith(Constants.avlApiRootUrl)) {
        return from(this._authService.getAccessToken()).pipe(
            map(token => new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${ token }`)),
            map(headers => req.clone({headers})),
            mergeMap(authReq => next.handle(authReq))
        );
   }

   return next.handle(req)
}
```

The reason for the `mergeMap` at the end is because we want to emit the emissions from `next.handle()`, not the `next.handle()` observable itself.

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer to my question